# How do I remove my label if price meets 200D MA conditions?

Tags: pine-script

Trying not to display the buy label if the price is below the 200D ma. (Bear Market) Also don't want to display the sell label when price is above the 200D ma (BullMarket)

That's really all I'm trying to do.
I wrote this out of instinct, but not working. Can't find how to fix it online. Need help! Thanks! :)

```
if (close < BullMarket)
buy = display.none




indicator("Redlight-Greenlight", overlay=true)


GreenLightMA = ta.sma(close, 7)
RedLightEMA = ta.ema(close, 47)
BullMarket = ta.sma(close, 200)

plot(GreenLightMA, color = color.green)
plot(RedLightEMA, color = color.red)
plot(BullMarket, color = color.orange)


buy = ta.crossover(GreenLightMA, RedLightEMA)
sell = ta.crossover(RedLightEMA, GreenLightMA)

if (buy)
lbl = label.new(bar_index, low, "Buy")
label.set_color(lbl, color.green)
label.set_yloc(lbl, yloc.belowbar)
label.set_style(lbl, label.style_label_up)

if (close < BullMarket)
buy = display.none

if (sell)
lbl = label.new(bar_index, low, "Sell")
label.set_color(lbl, color.red)
label.set_yloc(lbl, yloc.abovebar)
label.set_style(lbl, label.style_label_down)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just modify your `buy` and `sell` conditions to include the restriction.

```
buy = ta.crossover(GreenLightMA, RedLightEMA) and close > BullMarket
sell = ta.crossover(RedLightEMA, GreenLightMA) and close < BullMarket
```

You also need to be aware of indentations. `if` blocks require that code that is part of the if block be indented one tab.

```
//@version=5
indicator("Redlight-Greenlight", overlay=true)

GreenLightMA = ta.sma(close, 7)
RedLightEMA = ta.ema(close, 47)
BullMarket = ta.sma(close, 200)

plot(GreenLightMA, color = color.green)
plot(RedLightEMA, color = color.red)
plot(BullMarket, color = color.orange)


buy = ta.crossover(GreenLightMA, RedLightEMA) and close > BullMarket
sell = ta.crossover(RedLightEMA, GreenLightMA) and close < BullMarket

if (buy)
    lbl = label.new(bar_index, low, "Buy")
    label.set_color(lbl, color.green)
    label.set_yloc(lbl, yloc.belowbar)
    label.set_style(lbl, label.style_label_up)

if (sell)
    lbl = label.new(bar_index, low, "Sell")
    label.set_color(lbl, color.red)
    label.set_yloc(lbl, yloc.abovebar)
    label.set_style(lbl, label.style_label_down)
```

Comment: Omg, thanks so much. That's so simple, and it worked! This is my first script ever so I know the question sounds stupid, but thank you.